# Offering additional media resources (graphics/sounds) as Google Play in-app billed items

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Within my Android app that is available via Google Play, I want to offer additional items that can be bought via in-app billing.

The kind of items I want to offer is media content such as graphics and sounds, which would normally go into the `res` folder of the app.

The problem is that these resources must be protected, of course. In its [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html), Google suggests not to store the content inside of the application package but to obtain a key after the item was bought and then send the key to a remote server where the key is checked and, if successful, the graphics/sounds offered for download to the app.

This sounds good, from the security perspective. But if I do this, I can't use the content as easily as resources can be accessed normally. If the user can get additional background PNGs, for example, I can't use `R.drawable.new_background` but have to decode the bitmap programatically, right?

So are there any alternatives or best practices for downloading additional media content via in-app billing?

I would say, as everyone who is determined enough can reverse-engineer the code, anyway, why not just store the content inside of the app but do strong checks if the user might use that content at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of obvious reasons for not storing additional content in the app is your app's app download size. If you are offering audio as additional content it can drammatically increase the size of your application. And users care about it. Besides it makes it easier to publish additional content, since you can do it via your server side/developer console without the need to publish app update. Moreover, if you want to provide high quality graphics, you will be able to serve appropriate version of the image directly to the device without the need of storing all density/screen size versions.

If you are concerned about security you can always use encryption and signatures to access resources and make attackers life much harder by properly obfuscating your code (or even moving security/decryption related code to native side, which will make it faster as well).

Yes, that would create a drawback that you will have to decode them programmatically and there is nothing to do about it. I honestly don't see why it is so big of a deal, on contrary, I think it's quite convenient that you will have more data driven access to resources.

As a summary I dont really think there are any standards for doing this and it depends on your app and content type. If you offer a fixed amout of 5-10 images, then there it is perfectly fine to keep them locally, if it is richer content, more items, heavier resources, then client-server would suit you more.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends somewhat on your specific concerns, which, from your question, might be either 1 or 2 below:

1) I'm concerned that someone will be able to use my resource *within* my app without paying, or

2) I'm concerned that a user (*either* one who has paid, *or* one who has *not* paid) will remove my resources and use them *outside* my app.

Another possibility, that does not seem to be indicated by your question (but which others have attempted to address) would be:

3) I'm concerned about my initial APK download being too large due to downloading a large number of resources, only some of which they user will decide to use.

If your only concern is item 1, then you can just store your resources as you normally would, but inside your app, refuse to load / use any resource for which you have not yet received an in-app payment.  This is certainly the simplest approach.

If your concern is item 2, then you can just include with your APK an encrypted binary archive in the raw folder, and decode a specific resource from it whenever that resource is authorized (e.g., by payment) for use by the app.  As others have noted, this is not really a big deal in terms of processor load, and it does provide some protection from casual theft.  Of course, there is always copyright law if you're dealing with one of those "creative plagiarist" oxymorons who breaks your encryption and steals your resources anyway.

If your concern is item 3, then you'll need an external server from which your items can be retrieved.
Google App Engine is a popular choice for hosting when implementing this kind of storage outside the app.  You would want to just cache any purchased /downloaded resources in an encrypted archive in your app's own external files folder (as returned by getExternalFilesDir()), then read and decrypt it as in item 2, above.  Such files will be automatically deleted when your app is uninstalled.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm only concerned about (2), so this is the passage that is important to me. Unfortunately, your solution does not help in my case, I guess, because I have 50-100 drawables that need to be accessed by paying users. If I have to decrypt them all on runtime from the "raw" folder - I don't think that is going to work well.

Comment: So, then, a paying user gets *all* of the drawables, and a non-paying user gets *none* of the drawables?

Comment: Yes, none of those _additional_ drawables, that's right. Say there are 20 drawables in the free app that are used in various places. Paying users can get 50-100 additional drawables. Imagine games where additional drawables can mean new clothes for players or new levels ;)

Comment: Well, if your 50-100 drawables are only actually on the screen one or two at a time, then, speaking technically, some form of lazy (as-needed) decryption from aforesaid raw binary archive might be your best bet.  However, any version of Android from ICS on has a simple snapshot capability, and on a rooted device you can get a snapshot in any case, so a determined person could just take whatever was displayed on the screen and save it to a file.  So I don't think you can protect resources designed to be displayed by technical means, if that is your goal.  Better to write a good EULA, IMHO.

Comment: Well, in my case, there are up to 20 drawables on screen at once. But I see that is a very special use case ... By the way, I don't care about paying users taking snapshots. They bought that content, thus they may use it. But users who have not bought that content yet (and have it on their phones, though) may not access it.

Comment: Then lazy loading / decryption might be the way to go.  Unless your app costs a fortune, not many people would be motivated enough to go to the trouble of extracting images from a binary archive when they could just pay a few bucks and get it with no effort, even if it were just a proprietary file format and not encrypted at all.  That could minimize your decryption overhead.  BTW, what you have described is much more my concern 1 above than my concern 2, as I see it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, actually it is a mixture of 1 and 2: I don't want non-paying users to be able to use the drawables outside of the app. The fact that non-paying users should not be able to actually _use_ the content inside the app should be obvious.

Comment: I've proposed an approach that makes it easier to pay than to try to steal the content.  That should make your non-paying users decide to pay rather than try to steal the content.  You need to think about what your real goals are rather than pursuing absolutes like "no non-paying user should ever be able to use my content."  Are you trying to maximize revenue, or are you trying to protect intellectual property?  Anyway, SO is telling me that this comment thread has gone on too long, so think about your goals and see what seems like the best approach to you.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would definitely be the following approach featuring two apps that share the same user ID. But this is not as elegant as in-app purchases and a bit hacky, obviously.

1. Create two apps with the same `android:sharedUserId` in `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Store the paid content in the second app, that is a library app from now on and only contains those images (apart from necessary folders and manifest)
3. Sign both APKs with the same key
4. Offer the first app for free, as usual, and make the second app a paid one
5. In the free app, use the `PackageManager` to check if the second APK is installed
6. If yes, use `createPackageContext()` to create a `Context` for the second app which is then used to access the second app's resources from the first app

Comment: `sharedUserId` is not recommended for non-system apps, it might lead to some subtle issues (search android-developers for details). Other than that, this could work.

Comment: Yes, it is not recommended, as it is a bit "hackish", but I see no negative side effects other than that you cannot change it anymore after you have published the app.

Comment: There are different subtle side effects: for example one app is killed (while updating for example), the other will be too. Also both will look as a single app to the system. And of course, if your app is already published, adding sharedUserId will change the UID and you will lose access to private files you have created. All in all, rather tricky, but if you start with it from the beginning might work.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the the other app being killed as well if one app is killed by the system. That makes sense, of course. I know it's not the perfect solution, this is why I'm asking for alternatives here.

Comment: You already know the alternative is: use in-app billing to enable features. If you can bundle everything in the same app, do so. If not (because of size, etc.), download to private storage when the user buys the corresponding item(s). Loading stuff programmatically is not that much work anyways.

Comment: I will use in-app billing in order to enable features, anyway. But the problem is: The content that may be bought must not be available in the app package when the free app is installed. That protected content may only be available to paying users. And if I download the content from a web server, I can't access the graphis/sounds as app resources. This is the problem. And my approach with `android:sharedUserId` is one way to solve this problem ;)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with loading stuff from files instead of using resources? More code to write?

Comment: Resources are automatically cached, aren't they? And apart from that, they are easier to access and without exceptions that need to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play offers extension packs that can be purchased. These are large extensions that can be downloaded if purchased, and are separate from your app. This is one possibility.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Depending on how secure you want it, and the size of the media, you can encrypt the media with a key, and store it with your app. It will be downloaded and installed with the app, but inaccessible. When the in-app purchase is complete, you can decrypt the contents and offer it to the user. You can either store the key in the source code with the app to decrypt it, or you can verify the purchase on your own server and retrieve the key from your server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The expansion files are by no means inaccessible, as they are automatically downloaded to external storage, where everyone can access it. So there's no advantage over including the files in the APK or manually downloading them. In both cases, I could encrypt the contents as well. Thus expansion files are not an adequate solution.

Comment: The expansion files cannot be "purchased", they are part of the initial app transaction (free/paid). They are normally downloaded at the same time as the APK, you have to implement a mechanism to download them anyway should the initial download have failed. 
So you cannot use them at all to download content only after an in-app purchase.