# Android: Order ID of the purchased app

Tags: android, google-play, unique

We are planning to move from a paid app to a free one with in app purchase. We need to give any user, who paid for the app, get the in app purchase for free.

I am thinking of the following solution. We will store user's unique ID (or unique Order ID) inside our servers. When we release a new, free version of the app, we can check the unique user ID (or Order ID) against our server. If there is a match, we give them the in app purchase for free.

The question is:

- If we get the user's email, that would be too sensitive, and user may
  not be willing to give it.
- Can we get the order ID of the app, and check it against our Google
  Play list of order IDs?
- Any other unique IDs of the user that we can use to verify that they
  have bought the app before?

Answer (score 1):

Getting email address will need you to modify your existing Paid app. Also it's not recommended for above approach ( + cases where users have multiple accounts in same phone and doesn't remember which email is used will create more issues)

I would recommend to use https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid

**android:sharedUserId**

> The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other
>   applications. By default, Android assigns each application its own
>   unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same value
>   for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID —
>   provided that they are also signed by the same certificate.
>   Application with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if
>   desired, run in the same process.

Define same userId across paid app and new FREE app with in-app purchases. Certain data within paid app can be used to identify the user without asking any more input from users.

Take a look at one of solution provided in this answer by user caw [Offering additional media resources (graphics/sounds) as Google Play in-app billed items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510165/offering-additional-media-resources-graphics-sounds-as-google-play-in-app-bill)

Comment: So this assumes pushing an update, that include `android:sharedUserId` to the existing app and also releasing the new app with `android:sharedUserId`. What happens, if user does not update the previous app? That would mean, that they cannot access each other data, which makes these approach useless. Do I get it right?

Comment: If sharedUserId is already used in existing app, all we need to do is use that id in new app. If not yes, you need to release an update. You can always prompt user in new app to update to new version of existing production app. This is the best and easy solution that I have noted in above scenario rather than asking user for email address etc. If you come across a better solution, please update

Comment: @AmodGokhale thanks for your answer. But our new free app will replace the paid app, so we only have 1 app in the app store.