# Android licensing check from app A if app B has been purchased

Tags: android, google-play, licensing, billing

I have been following the Android Licensing tutorial and i have been able to check license of a paid app by querying Google Servers, what i cant understand is if it would be possible to check from an app A (es a free app) if another app B (the pro key) has been purchased without setting up complex workflows on the pro app (i am now checking the signature and then using a provider to ensure B has checked license form A)

Comment: Did you tried just to check if there is package from app B present?

Comment: yes- Android:SharedUserId - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401051/android-order-id-of-the-purchased-app/44404830#44404830

Comment: @AmodGokhale i cant use shared user id, the apps are already published (with the same account)

Comment: @Ekalips thats not a way to check if the user bought the app from the play store

Comment: @FrankMonza - if possible release an update with shared user Id. That will be easiest way to get data across. If not SharedUserId, couple of ways 1. Content Providers https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html or using 2. IABHelper and sending base64EncodedPublicKey of Pro app in demo app to get licenses ( You might want to add Developer payload in pro app for additional check )

Comment: @AmodGokhale shared id cannot be changed after release, as mentioned i am currently using a content provider but i dont like the solution